# [next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR] outgoing request timed out after 3500ms with google provider

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, next-auth, next.js13

I am using nextjs 13 with nextauth with google provider and prisma adapter, when i tried signin first time after setup it works well but after that it start showing error.

**FUll error:**

```bash
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error outgoing request timed out after 3500ms {
  error: RPError: outgoing request timed out after 3500ms
      at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/openid-client@5.4.3/node_modules/openid-client/lib/helpers/request.js:115:19)
      at async Issuer.discover (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/openid-client@5.4.3/node_modules/openid-client/lib/issuer.js:135:30)
      at async openidClient (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next-auth@4.23.0_next@13.4.13_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/client.js:12:18)
      at async oAuthCallback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next-auth@4.23.0_next@13.4.13_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/callback.js:94:24)
      at async Object.callback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next-auth@4.23.0_next@13.4.13_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:18:79)
      at async AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next-auth@4.23.0_next@13.4.13_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:202:38)
      at async NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next-auth@4.23.0_next@13.4.13_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:50:30)
      at async NextAuth._args$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next-auth@4.23.0_next@13.4.13_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:84:24)
      at async eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.13_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:254:37) {
    name: 'OAuthCallbackError',
    code: undefined
  },
  providerId: 'google',
  message: 'outgoing request timed out after 3500ms'
}
```

Using Wsl 2 on window 11

```bash
WSL version: 1.2.5.0
Kernel version: 5.15.90.1
WSLg version: 1.0.51
MSRDC version: 1.2.3770
Direct3D version: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.2134
```

I tried the solution provided on github issue like:

- Wifi restart
- using personal mobile data
- laptop restart
- changed timeout in nextauthoptions

github [issue](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/3920)
But none of them works , I tried using github providor and its works well, issue is only with the google provider

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Yes , the problem was dns for me ,i changed my pc's dns settings  from default to google dns then it worked fine. I will edit the post